# my UITableViewCell setting button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm having trouble adding  button to my `UITableViewCell`, the cell has two `UILabel`s and two `UIImageView`s, sometimes the `UIImageView` will contain an image and sometimes a button:

[image]

In my `UITableViewCell` subclass I have:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if ( self ) {
        // Initialization code

    firstLock = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [firstLock setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    firstLock.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    firstLock.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17];

    secondLock= [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [secondLock setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    secondLock.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    secondLock.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17];

    firstLockImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

    secondLockImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    [self.contentView addSubview:firstLock];
    [self.contentView addSubview:secondLock];
    [self.contentView addSubview:firstLockImage];
    [self.contentView addSubview:secondLockImage];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When one of the `UIImageView`s is just an image no problem, but it crashes when I add  a `UIButton` (imaged) as a subview.

In the `UITableViewDataSource` implementation:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bike_ok.png"];

UIButton *button =[UIButton alloc];
[button setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[cell.secondLockImage addSubview:button];
```

Adding a button as a subview of the image view crashes:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Requesting the window of a view (<UIButton: 0x7bac7d0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = (null)>) with a nil layer. This view probably hasn't received initWithFrame: or initWithCoder:.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Just add! its important this line

```
    [firstLockImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [secondLockImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Because the UIImageView has NO as default and the button doesn't work without it!

Comment: Am I missing something ? I cannot see where you are creating (and reusing) the cell itself in your code. The action typically done in tableView:cellForRow:

Comment: I only copy the relevant code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the crash error it is quite easy to see where your issue is. You have not initialized your button.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];
```

or you can use initWithCoder.

Hope this helps

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Read the exception text - it says:

> This view probably hasn't received initWithFrame: or initWithCoder:

Just a few lines up in your question, you are sending messages to a `UIButton` instance that you have only `alloc`'d and not sent any `init...` message to. That is your error.

<strike>Furthermore, you shouldn't directly call the `alloc`/`init` pair on `UIButton` as it's a class cluster and you should usually use `+[UIButton buttonWithType:]` to get a button instance.</strike>

**EDIT** I'm not 100% sure about that, actually. But you don't really know exactly what you'll get if you do `initWithFrame:` so I'd still go with `buttonWithType:` to get a custom button, which is what you want. **END EDIT**

So, change that line to:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very good explanation! I tried and if I init the button as you said, I have to add button.frame to set the frame.

Comment: Thank you! And yes you'd have to set the frame. You could also do `sizeToFit` after setting the image and that would probably give you a sensible default to start from.

Answer (score 1):

change `UIButton *button =[UIButton alloc];` (**alloc w/o init**?) to

```
UIButton *button =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//set frame
[button setFrame:(CGRect){x,y,w,h}];
```

`+buttonWithType` handles the alloc/init for your UIButton object