# This view probably hasn't received initWithFrame: or initWithCoder:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a `tableView` and have implemented its delegates and data source methods as well. I am not new with `tableViews` and delegates. But still I am getting this crash:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Requesting the window of a view (<UIView: 0xc8b7a00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = (null)>) with a nil layer. This view probably hasn't received initWithFrame: or initWithCoder:.'
```

I have used same code for many other `tableViews` which I am using for this one but I don't know where I am wrong and I also know that this is an old or repeated question but none of the previous solutions worked for me. Here are my delegate and data source methods.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    int numberOfRows = 0;
    if(section == 0){
        numberOfRows = [self.lotteryArray count];
    }else{
        numberOfRows = 10;
    }
    return numberOfRows;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cellToReturn = nil;

    LedenactiesCell *cell = (LedenactiesCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LedenactiesCell"];
    if(!cell){
        NSString *nibName = @"LedenactiesCellView";
        [self.cellOwner loadMyNibFile:nibName];
        cell = (LedenactiesCell *)self.cellOwner.cell;
    }
    cell.titleLbl = @"My Text for cell";
    cellToReturn = cell;
    return cellToReturn;
}
```

I have debugged my code and it never goes to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Any suggestions..

Comment: Add exception point and check at which line app crashes.

Comment: It goes to `numberOfRowsInSection` method and then crash. Where I should place break point.

Comment: Add Exception Breakpoint in xcode for your app.

Comment: I have done that already but it just shows me error but does not denote the line where this crash occurs.

Comment: Try "po 0xc8b7a00[replace this to the current memory address]" at the debugger after the crash, to see which view is causing the problem.
Maybe the problem is with an other view, and it crashes before the delegate method is called.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277287/my-uitableviewcell-setting-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialise properly the view containing the table. Use initWithFrame: or initialise it from the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

might be you are missing `if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]){}` in your `initWithStyle:` method.

try this hope this solve your problem.

```
 - (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

            if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]){

// initialise your objects here...


            } 
            return self;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you initialize the property before you use it.  In my case I have initialized textfield property in viewDidLoad but I have tried to use it somewhere else.

wrong

```
  -(Void)viewDidLoad
    {
    textField = [UITextField alloc]init];
    }

And I am using here

    -(void)someMethod
    {
    textField.text = @"sdsfs";
    }
I got error.....

Right way is 

    -(void)someMethod
        {
        textField = [UITextField alloc]init];
        textField.text = @"sdsfs";
        }

I hope it helps to someone.
```